# RequestDispatcher.include(...) appends servlet's package name

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have an index.jsp page which uploads an image. On submit it goes to a servlet Upload.java. In the servlet I am checking if the extension in of image("jpg","png",etc) and forwards to new jsp page else it shows an error message and includes the same index.jsp page.

My servlet is a package named "servlets".

If I select an image then it is working properly. But if I select any file other than image then it shows the error with the index.jsp page as intended. Till now it works fine but if I upload any file even image from here, the server complains.

Here is how I am including the index.jsp page in UploadServlet.java servlet.

```
out.println("This type of file is not allowed. Please select an image.");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

Here is the error from the server when I try to upload the image second time.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /UploadImage/servlets/servlets/UploadServlet
```

---

```
type Status report

message /UploadImage/servlets/servlets/UploadServlet

description The requested resource (/CropImage/servlets/servlets/UploadServlet) is not available.
```

---

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
```

It is appending the servlet's package name to the url.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: it is working fine in firefox but the problem is in IE.

Comment: Manohar, this is not true. It should have the same problem. It's just your misinterpretation of the problem.

Comment: I checked it in firefox and it worked fine I don't know how. But in IE it is giving problem. I will try your answer given below and let you all know. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're using a relative action URL in your `<form>`.

```html
<form action="servlets/UploadServlet" ...>
```

When you open `index.jsp`, the request URL is

> http://localhost:8080/UploadImage/index.jsp

When you submit the form, the action URL is relative to the current folder, so request URL will be

> http://localhost:8080/UploadImage/servlets/UploadServlet

When you submit the form once again, the will be still relative to current folder, so you end up in

> http://localhost:8080/UploadImage/servlets/servlets/UploadServlet

You need to fix it to be a domain-relative URL, starting with a leading slash.

```html
<form action="/UploadImage/servlets/UploadServlet" ...>
```

This way the URL will be resolved relative to the domain root. You can also resolve the context path dynamically by `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlets/UploadServlet" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC your answer solved my problem.
I used
 <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlets/UploadServlet" ...>
 and the problem got solved.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd however suggest you to take benefit of the `doGet()` method of the servlet so that you end up with cleaner URLs. See also our servlets wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong. You can open the `web.xml` and find the "servlet-mapping" element there you can find the mapping url.

I guess your url may be `"/CropImage/servlets/UploadServlet"` .you can try to delete one "servlets" in the url.

Comment: <servlet>
  <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
  <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
  <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlets.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet><servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlets/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>